# XOR Crypt Haskell

Tags: haskell

I am trying to encrypt a String with a Key given as an argument using XOR from Data.Bits, as well, I am trying to learn how to create this in Haskell.

Please note that I am new to this programming language and I would like to learn by myself how to do this. If possible, I would like to get some hints on how to do it

What I tought off till now:

```
encrypt string = map xor $ split "" string
```

Yet I don't really know how to use a Key to encrypt it, where should I add it? Maybe repeat the map "Key" times?

The function signature is
String -> [Word8] -> [Word8]
And I am trying to create it point-free(only with the string argument)

Comment: is the key supposed to be the same length as you input (one-time-pad style) or do you want to *repeat* it? - Also isn't the function supposed to be either `String -> String -> String` or `String -> String -> [Word8]` or `[Word8] -> [Word8] -> [Word8]`?

Comment: now matter what: have a look at `zipWith`

Comment: @Carsten The key is supposed to be the same length as the input, and the function should be as I said above because I can covert the key from String to Word8 and backwards

Comment: you convert a `String` to `Word8`?  - you mean `[Word8]`? Anyway if you know this it's really just `zipWith xor` instead of the `map`

Comment: @Carsten looked at zipWith, should I do it in the following way 'encrypt str = zipWith xor str (convertToWord8 key)' ,I still do not know how to make it point-free tough

Comment: I'll never understand the fascination with point-free - but look closely - why don't you switch the arguments a bit and see what it gives you: `encrypt str = zipWith xor (convertToWord8 key) str`

Comment: btw: this does not seem to match your signature - isn't the key supposed to be a `[Word8]` and the `string` a `String`?

Comment: @Carsten I am currently not at home, I am actually posting from a phone, but as soon as I do that, i will post here. One more question tough: Given the same situation but wanting to encrypt the same string with a map array [(Char, Char)] ex [("A", "B")] will encrypt all A's into B's how would I do that? As well with a zipwith? But with what operator?

Comment: @Carsten Yes, the key should be [Word8] and the str a String

Answer (score 1):

Judging from your comments, you want to have this in point-free style:

```
encrypt = zipWith xor . convertToWord8
```

There is a tool called "[pointfree](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/pointfree)" which can automatically convert expressions to pointfree style.

Comments:

- Do not over-do point-free style. Anything but very short snippets may easily become unreadable. That is because point-free style can obfuscate the structure of the expression, and it strips away helpful variable names.
- Do not call your function *encrypt* if it only obfuscates.